# how to call sub query in if conditional statement on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables table1 and table2. i need value of table1 when status=1

```
    SELECT type, no, 
        CASE WHEN status = '0' THEN 'Vacant'
             WHEN status = '2' THEN 'Repair'
             ELSE (SELECT `field1` FROM `table1` WHERE `field2`=10) AS test END AS addr 
FROM table2
```

This query outputs error with #1064

how can I get the values in a single MYSQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT type, no, 
    CASE WHEN status = '0' THEN 'Vacant'
         WHEN status = '2' THEN 'Repair'
         WHEN status = '1' (SELECT `field1` FROM `table1` WHERE `field2`=10) END AS addr FROM table2
```

if you try this code then you won't get error

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
WHERE s11 > ANY
 (SELECT COUNT(*) /* no hint */ FROM t2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT * FROM t3
   WHERE ROW(5*t2.s1,77)=
    (SELECT 50,11*s1 FROM t4 UNION SELECT 50,77 FROM
     (SELECT * FROM t5) AS t5)));
```